# How to navigate between pages in windows universal app using C++/CX

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am new to Windows universal app development. As per my knowledge Windows universal app can be made by using **C++/CX** , **C#** or **JavaScript.** But Microsoft force to do development by using **C++/CX** because it uses power of winRT much better than others. So i tried the development using **C++/CX for Visual Studio 2015.** 
I come to a topic of Navigation. To perform navigation in app there is one API
**this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(MySecondPage::typeid))**. This API gives me a exception at runtime.

This is the detail scenario what i did.
1. I create project by named **NavigationSample** using C++/CX.

2. Then i added new Basic Page of xaml for my Second view/ui and named it as **MySecondPage.xaml**
3. Now on first page i.e. **MainPage.xaml**    i added  One  button.
4. On event of this button , lets say  button_Click as event handler i wrote
   **this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(MySecondPage::typeid))**

Here is the detailed code:

void  **NavigationSample::MainPage::button_Click(**Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e**)**

**{**

```
this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(MySecondPage::typeid));
```

**}**

5. This compile and build fine. But gives exception at runtime. (Same scenario works very fine with C#)

   So guys please help me how to resolve this issue?
   Thanks

Comment: "It gives an exception" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: It gives me following Exception:  "Exception thrown at 0x000007777 in NavigationSample.windows.exe Microsoft C++ exception. HRESULT 0x0007777f parameter is incorrect.      WinRT Information:dp"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clue:

```
m_ptrSettingsPage->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal, ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this]() {
            m_ptrSettingsPage->Frame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(AnnuitiesPage::typeid));
        }));
```

Best wait for C++/wimRT